# Array objects are not updated using dot notation or brackets notation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to copy the size property of every object in dataArr to the corespondent size property of objects in testArr. I have problem to understand (and I'm surprised) why it is not working.

CODE:

```js
var testArr = [
          {one : '1'},
          {two : '2'},
          {three : '3'}
        ];

var dataArr = [
          {number : '0', size : '111'},
          {number : '1', size : '222'},
          {number : '2', size : '333'}
        ];

dataArr.forEach(function(item, index)
{
  if (testArr[item.number] = item.number)
  {
    console.log('testArr[item.number] - ' + testArr[item.number]); // correct
    console.log('item.size - ' + item.size); // correct
    testArr[item.number].size = item.size; // not working
    testArr[item.number]['size'] = item.size; // not working either
    // WTF?!
  }
});
console.log(testArr);
```

So why my testArr is not properly updated?

Comment: Typo: `=` in the `if` condition should be `==`.

Comment: single `=` is for assignment not for comparison. Also `testArr[item.number]` returns an object, not a single number

Comment: Using single equals `=` in an `if` test is almost always a mistake.

Comment: @ASDFGerte It can be useful with truthy/falsy.

Comment: ohhh thank you, problems is solved!

Comment: @Tân in iterations using `while`, yes, but in `if`, it's so uncommon, that using it will harm readability over doing the assignment before the `if`. I bet many linters and styleguides will complain about it. There may be some edge-cases, hence why i stated "almost".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testArr[item.number]` is an object like `{one: '1'}`, but `item.number` is a string. So they will never be equal, and the `if` test always fails.

But the reason you're getting into the `if` block is because you used `=` rather than `==`, so you're assigning instead of comparing.

You need to search `testArr` for the element whose value is the same as `item.number`.

```js
var testArr = [
          {one : '1'},
          {two : '2'},
          {three : '3'}
        ];

var dataArr = [
          {number : '0', size : '111'},
          {number : '1', size : '222'},
          {number : '2', size : '333'}
        ];

dataArr.forEach(function(item)
{
  var obj = testArr.find(obj => Object.values(obj)[0] == item.number);
  if (obj) {
    obj.size = item.size;
  }
});
console.log(testArr);
```

In general, an array of objects that each have a different key is usually poor design, because you can't access the property easily.

Comment: I did use ARRAY.findIndex() at the end, but thanks for pointing possible solution to another problem that somebody can have when reading the comments. Very nice of you to thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said. You have 2 errors in this line:

```
if (testArr[item.number] = item.number)
```

1. You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of equality operator `==`, and you should really use the type safe equality operator `===` to prevent erroneous type comparisons such as `0 == false` returning `true`.
2. Even if you were using the correct operator, `testArr` contains objects, but you are comparing the object to a string `item.number` which doesn't make sense and will return false.